# PHP Array with Key Values don't match

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a query that I'm running in php. The DB is SQL Server 2008.
The query in PHP is:

```
"SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE applicants.families_id = '{$family_array['id']}'";
```

Where the `$family_array` id is matched against the `families_id`. I get a single row as a result. I save that row to an array in PHP by using the `mssql_fetch_array` function. When I print this array I get the following:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 26
    [id] => 21
    [1] => 21
    [user_id] => 21
    [2] => Kristi
    [mother_fname] => Kristi
    [3] => Lochala
    [mother_lname] => Lochala
    [4] => Nathan
    [father_fname] => Nathan
    [5] => Lochala
    [father_lname] => Lochala
    [6] => 
    [app_emergency] => 
    [7] => 
    [upload_mother_passport] => 
    [8] => 
    [upload_mother_visa] => 
    [9] => 
    [upload_father_passport] => 
    [10] => 0
    [upload_father_visa] => 0
    [11] => nathan-lochala
    [user_added_username] => nathan-lochala
    [12] => Mar 19 2013 01:00:37:660PM
    [user_added_date] => Mar 19 2013 08:48:00:000AM
    [13] => 192.168.88.15
    [user_added_ip] => 192.168.88.15
    [14] => 
    [user_updated_username] => 
    [15] => 
    [user_updated_date] => 
    [16] => 
    [user_updated_ip] => 
    [17] => 21
    [18] => nathan-lochala
    [username] => nathan-lochala
    [19] => b9a234cb37ce2b75d77befecabfa650e39489e0b
    [hash_password] => b9a234cb37ce2b75d77befecabfa650e39489e0b
    [20] => Nathan
    [fname] => Nathan
    [21] => Lochala
    [lname] => Lochala
    [22] => 2
    [num_child] => 2
    [23] => Mar 19 2013 08:48:00:000AM
    [24] => 192.168.88.15
    [25] => 
    [26] => 
    [27] => nathan-lochala@shk.qsi.org
    [email] => nathan-lochala@shk.qsi.org
    [28] => parent
    [access] => parent
)
```

If you notice, the `index [0]` does not match the corresponding key value `[id]`. Why is this? I've ran the exact same query using the SQL Server Manager and it performs as expected, but when I fetch that array in PHP only the first key value gets skewed. I've tried everything I can think of short of recreating the table. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Running mssql_fetch_assoc() gives me the following results:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 21
    [user_id] => 21
    [mother_fname] => Kristi
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the query in your Server Manager again and paste in the results so we can see them.

Comment: Looks like 26 is the id and 21 is the "foreign key"

Comment: Please list *all* the columns returned by the query.

Comment: Above is an edit where I've added all the columns in the array, thus all the columns in my table.

Comment: Nathan, we need to see what the column names look like *before* PHP places them into an array. It would be more helpful to see the full results from SQL Server.

Comment: I've added a picture of the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including all the pertinent information either in the posted SQL or in the table data/structure you've included. Your query is `SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE applicants.families_id = ?` yet the table structure you've posted does not contain a `families_id` column (nor is it named `applicants`). Nor does it contain much of the data in the posted array, e.g., `hash_password`, `username`, etc.

From this I deduce that you're actually doing a JOIN on a `users` table. What's most likely occurring is that **the JOIN is including the `id` column from the `users` table which is overwriting the `id` in the main table (families/applicant, whatever it's called) once the array is built**. `user_id` is already included in your main table so you should explicitly list the columns in your SQL statement, leaving out the `users.id` column.

Comment: I didn't realize until now. You are absolutely right. There were actually a few things going on here. My initial query, the one posted in my question, was being over written by a different query with the same variable name in a different part of my script. That query had an inner join which was over ridding my array. Thank you so much for your solution. You were SPOT ON!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it `mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)` as MSSQL_BOTH is assumed.

I found the answer here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php

Comment: No dice, they are still not matching. They being the id value in the array and the table's id value.